# Up-to-date ribbon control for WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I am new to WPF and I need a ribbon control for my app.
I see there are lots of ribbon controls, it is confusing to choose
which one and why to use it. Can you please suggest me which one to use?
I use WPF and Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `RibbonControl` was first introduced, it was an optional add-on to the .NET Framework. However, now in .NET 4.5, the `RibbonControl` is included. Therefore I would recommend that you use this latest version if you can.

Also, if you have seen a `RibbonControl` on the `CodePlex` website, then you should know that this is in fact comprised of the *same* set of UI controls.

You can find out more about the `RibbonControl` from the [RibbonControl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontrol.aspx) page on the official MSDN website.

Comment: You mean this one: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877 ?

Comment: No, I mean the one that is included with the .NET 4.5 Framework. You should already have the dlls for it if you have Visual Studio 2012 and version 4.5 of the Framework. To be honest with you, I am still using the version that you added a link to as I was using it before .NET 4.5 came out. I've had no problems with that version either.